# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am updating a variable with a splice of an existing array inside of an if statement which should then run my loop only on the updated array, however I keep getting a cannot read property 'replace' of undefined on my values array.  I am only getting this error because I have to input the value plus one array index as I need the upper of the two value ranges. (values[i + 1].replace(',', '').  Any ideas why the + 1 is causing the replace to see values as undefined?  Thanks in advance for any help possible!

```
dropDown = function (arg) {
if ($('select[name="est_property_value"]').length != 0) {
    var values = ["0", "60,000", "85,000", "90,000", "95,000", "100,000", "105,000", "110,000", "115,000", "120,000", "125,000", "130,000", "135,000", "140,000", "145,000", "150,000", "155,000", "160,000", "165,000", "170,000", "175,000", "180,000", "185,000", "190,000", "195,000", "200,000", "210,000", "220,000", "230,000", "240,000", "250,000", "260,000", "270,000", "280,000", "290,000", "300,000", "310,000", "320,000", "330,000", "340,000", "350,000", "360,000", "370,000", "380,000", "390,000", "400,000", "420,000", "440,000", "460,000", "480,000", "500,000", "520,000", "540,000", "560,000", "580,000", "600,000", "620,000", "640,000", "660,000", "680,000", "700,000", "720,000", "740,000", "760,000", "780,000", "800,000", "820,000", "840,000", "860,000", "880,000", "900,000", "920,000", "940,000", "960,000", "980,000", "1,000,000", "1,500,000"],
        anchor = $('select[name="est_property_value"]').val();

    // default arg loads larger ltv on page load
    if (arg === 'default') {
        values = values.splice(0, 18);
    }
    console.log(values);
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            valueToInt = values[i].replace(',', '');
            if (valueToInt < parseInt(anchor)) {
                curValue = '<option value="' + values[i + 1].replace(',', '') + 1 + '">' + '$' + values[i] + ' - $' + values[i + 1] + '</option>';
                $('select[name="mortgage_amount"]').append(curValue);
            }

        }


}
return;
```

}

Comment: you cannot access `values[i+1]` when i = `values.length - 1`. It will be `undefined`. Maybe you should run the loop to `values.length - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in question, `i + 1` make that problem. because it does not exists in your array. You can use a condition in for loop so when the next element exists, Use that. And when You get to the last element of array, use **0** for example.

Change your for loop to this

```js
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  valueToInt = values[i].replace(',', '');
  if (valueToInt < parseInt(anchor)) {
    curValue = '<option value="' + (values[i + 1] ? values[i + 1] : '0').replace(',', '') + 1 + '">' + '$' + values[i] + ' - $' + (values[i + 1] ? values[i + 1] : '0') + '</option>';
    $('select[name="mortgage_amount"]').append(curValue);
  }

}
```

Comment: Your snippet works great!! Thank you so much! Thanks for adding the ternary in there.